# Autofixture for a List of Object that has a protected constructor and a factory method

Tags: c#, .net, autofixture

```
public partial class TestObjectCode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// We don't make constructor public and forcing to create object using
    /// <see cref="Create"/> method.
    /// But constructor can not be private since it's used by EntityFramework.
    /// Thats why we did it protected.
    /// </summary>
    protected TestObjectCode() {}

    public static  TestObjectCode Create(
                    DateTime executiontime,
                    Int32 conditionid,
                    String conditionname)
    {
        var @objectToReturn = new TestObjectCode
        {

            ExecutionTime = executiontime,
            ConditionId = conditionid,
            ConditionName = conditionname
        };

        return @objectToReturn;
    }

    public virtual Int32 ConditionId { get; set; }

    public virtual String ConditionName { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime ExecutionTime { get; set; }
}
```

Test:

```
[Test]
[TestCase("1/1/2015", "07/5/2016")]
public void Task Should_Filter_By_Date_Range_Only(string startDate, string endDate)
{
    //Arrange
    var startDateTime = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
    var endDateTime = DateTime.Parse(endDate);

    //get randomDate between two Dates
    TimeSpan timeSpan = endDateTime - startDateTime;
    var randomTest = new Random();
    TimeSpan newSpan = new TimeSpan(0, randomTest.Next(0, (int)timeSpan.TotalMinutes), 0);
    DateTime newDate = startDateTime + newSpan;

    var list = new List<TestObjectCode>();
    _fixture.AddManyTo(list);
    _fixture.Customize<TestObjectCode>(
        c => c
        .With(x => x.ExecutionTime, newDate)
        .With(x => x.ConditionId, 1)
        );
    _fixture.RepeatCount = 7;
    _fixture.AddManyTo(list);
}
```

Above test fails due to  _fixture.Customize and my ctor being proetced. if i make it public it works, but i would like to make it proected. this class has 15 more properties i did not list here. also i wanted a randmon date between two dateRanges for each item in list.

How can i call the factory Create method ? do i need to do define autoFixure for each property?

> Ploeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException : The decorated ISpecimenBuilder could not create a specimen based on the request: EMR.Entities.AbpAuditLogs. This can happen if the request represents an interface or abstract class; if this is the case, register an ISpecimenBuilder that can create specimens based on the request. If this happens in a strongly typed Build expression, try supplying a factory using one of the IFactoryComposer methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the above test pass by adding `.FromFactory(new MethodInvoker(new FactoryMethodQuery()))` to your customization:

```
fixture.Customize<TestObjectCode>(
    c => c
    .FromFactory(new MethodInvoker(new FactoryMethodQuery()))
    .With(x => x.ExecutionTime, newDate)
    .With(x => x.ConditionId, 1));
```

Both of these classes are defined in the `Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel` namespace.

All that said, though, you should [strongly reconsider your overall approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28633780/126014).

Comment: that does work but , only first object in the list follows the customize rules, for _fixture.AddManyTo(list);   rest of the items are random