# Force autofixture to pass argument to specific constructor

Tags: autofixture

I have to use a [specific constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425521/force-autofixture-to-use-the-greediest-constructor) with auto fixture customization.
The application logic requires to change the temperature unit through the constructor. Otherwise the temperature values will be converted and i can't determine the minimum temperature. Is it possible to modify the used constructor parameter?

#### Update

This seems to be a work around for me:

```
var tempUnit = new Fixture().Create<TemperatureUnit>();
var temperatureFixture = new Fixture();
//... 
temperatureFixture.Customizations.Add(new RandomNumericSequenceGenerator(Convert.ToInt64(GetMinTemperatureForUnit(tempUnit)), long.MaxValue));   

//workaround to force autofixture to create weather with unit
weatherFixture.Register<TemperatureUnit>(() => tempUnit);
weatherFixture.Customize<Weather>(weather => weather.FromFactory(new MethodInvoker(new GreedyConstructorQuery()))
            .With(x => x.Temperature, temperatureFixture.Create<double>())
            .Without(x => x.TempUnit)
```

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate, but I can't quite divine from the question exactly what the scenario is, so I'll start with suggesting this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28603831/126014

Comment: My problem description was unclear, I edited the question

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. Could you share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?